# How to embed Camunda Task forms in Custom Portal

Tags: camunda

We have our own custom build web portal (built on AngualrJS,etc). We would like to have the functionality similar to Camunda's Tasklist UI. What is the recommended approach to replicate the functionality? Is it possible to embed Just tasklist UI and refer the forms using embedded: forms in process?

Regards,

Phani

Comment: It depends a bit of your architecture and setup. But the Camunda tasklist can be, almost, served statically.

Answer (score 0):

In my application, I have created my own task list. I embed GSP (Groovy Server Pages) forms in my process JARs.

My application fetches these pages via the ["Get Single Deployment Resource" REST API](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.3/api-references/rest/#deployment-get-single-deployment-resource):

```
/deployment/{id}/resources/{resourceId}
```

Then the application renders the page.

Something similar could be done to serve up AngularJS pages.

Answer (score 0):

First a question.
Are you referring to the task forms that ar automatically generated by the Camunda Task list based on Form Properties (called [Generated Task Forms](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.3/guides/user-guide/#task-forms-generated-task-forms))?

If so, there is no way to easily embed just the form as the rendering is handled by the tasklist framework.

However, Camunda have a very nice Forms SDK that can be used to created [Embedded Forms](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.3/api-references/embedded-forms/#integrating-the-forms-sdk). Look for the heading "Integrating the Forms SDK" in the above link and you will see how to add the Camunda Forms SDK to your own HTML5 application.

This is something we cover in our standard training class.

Hope this helps.
Greg - BP3